# Magento 2.4.3p1: Compilation error

Tags: magento2, error, setup-di-compile

I am getting this error on compile:

```
Repositories code generation... 1/9 [===>------------------------]  11% < 1 sec 127.0 MiBsyntax error, unexpected 'parent' (T_STRING)#0 /home/737025.cloudwaysapps.com/zrguwnbdav/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#1 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call()
#3 /home/737025.cloudwaysapps.com/zrguwnbdav/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(134): class_exists()
#4 /home/737025.cloudwaysapps.com/zrguwnbdav/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(117): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->includeClass()
#5 /home/737025.cloudwaysapps.com/zrguwnbdav/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(87): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->extract()
#6 /home/737025.cloudwaysapps.com/zrguwnbdav/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/RepositoryGenerator.php(61): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->getList()
#7 /home/737025.cloudwaysapps.com/zrguwnbdav/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(56): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\RepositoryGenerator->doOperation()
#8 /home/737025.cloudwaysapps.com/zrguwnbdav/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php(216): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process()
#9 /home/737025.cloudwaysapps.com/zrguwnbdav/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute()
#10 /home/737025.cloudwaysapps.com/zrguwnbdav/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#11 /home/737025.cloudwaysapps.com/zrguwnbdav/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#12 /home/737025.cloudwaysapps.com/zrguwnbdav/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#13 /home/737025.cloudwaysapps.com/zrguwnbdav/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun()
#14 /home/737025.cloudwaysapps.com/zrguwnbdav/public_html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#15 {main}
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error in one of the third party extension. I found the issue by deleting the files and running the compile command. A ';' was missing in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

in my case the error was this "syntax error, unexpected '*'#0 /var/www/clients/client2/web8/web/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(325): Composer\Autoload\includeFile() " and this was because in my module I had a "*/"

I was able to see which file contained the error by modifying the "vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php" file on line 322. Added "print"\n File: ".$file;" after trying to compile again, when the error is printed, you can see which file contains that error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code having dependencies on `Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\*` classes.

Support for Mysql search adapter is removed in 2.4.

Please review your `Customization/Custom Third Party Extension` and remove this dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have disabled all the third party extensions but I am still getting the error.
I have also updated the complete error message.